# Swap default iOS system font in apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiappfonts

I'm trying to build an app to install a custom set of fonts for other ios apps to use. Is it possible to change iOS 6 default set of fonts and add a custom set of font that other apps can use?

Answer (score 1):

Custom (non-system) fonts must be included in an app's `.plist` file and must be included in the application bundle for an app to use them.

Since application bundles are read only, it is only possible for an app to use a non-system font that is included before it is distributed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. Apps basically can't change default configuration (like fonts, background, colors, icons, animations) from the whole OS. You can use custom fonts in your app though.